# Notice: product_type was called incorrectly . Product properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: woocommerce, types, product

Notice: product_type was called incorrectly . Product properties should not be accessed directly. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\oye\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4667. but when find

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: That means that somewhere, you have something like `$product->product_type` and it should need to be instead `$product->get_type()`.

Comment: $product->get_type() code already exist